# Send string from raspberry pi with Python to Arduino for starting led strip. How to select the right USB port?

Tags: python, arduino, usb, led, lsusb

I try to light up an led strip with Python sending the information to the USB port that has an Arduino and led strip on it.
I am having problems with the USB port. I don't know which one is the right one and how can I translate this port to Python language.

I found this python code and modified it:

```
import serial 

r = "255"

g = "0" 

b = "0" 

i = "255" 

data = r + "," + g +"," + b + "," + i print(data)

ser = serial.Serial(port='/dev/ttyUSB0',baudrate =
9600,parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS,timeout=1)

ser.write(data) 
ser.close()
```

So the problem is I don't know if it is the USB0 I tried from 0 to 3 and didn't work.

I tried lsusb and I can see the Arduino:

> Bus 001 Device 005: ID 2341:0043 Arduino SA Uno R3 (CDC ACM)

So it should be the 01? but it was not working then I tried this command: `python -m serial.tools.list_ports` and I get these ports

```
/dev/ttyACM0 
/dev/ttyAMA0
```

Tried to put them in place of port='/dev/ttyUSB0' and get permission error:

> Error could not open port /dev/ttyAMA0: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/dev/ttyAMA0'

solution

```
sudo chmod 666 /dev/ttyAMA0
```

And after doing it again I got:

> raise TypeError('unicode strings are not supported, please encode to bytes: {!r}'.format(seq))
> TypeError: unicode strings are not supported, please encode to bytes: '255,0,0,255'

Before I even continue I am not sure that this is the right USB port. So can someone tell me how can I detect them for example like the lsusb and understand how can I translate it to Python code.

Thank you all.

**SOLUTION**
See last device with this linux command

```
dmesg | grep "tty"
[    8.150923] cdc_acm 1-1.1:1.0: ttyACM0: USB ACM device
```

Comment: you have to write `data.encode()`

Comment: Try running `ls -lR /dev/serial/by-id` and then click [edit] and paste the output into your question.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you furas and Mark

furas yes the way to send the data is right. But my main question was about the usb port i was not sure witch one is the right one to place in the code.
Mark when i put the command it say can not access there is no such directory.

**SOLUTION**
Found this linux command in internet and they was saying that the last listed one should be the right one so this is the answer:

```
dmesg | grep "tty"
[    8.150923] cdc_acm 1-1.1:1.0: ttyACM0: USB ACM device
```

After seeng that the last tty is **ttyACM0** i put **port='/dev/ttyACM0'** and it works.
I have no idea why but is needed the 2 sec sleep. Because if it is less the led is not turning on.

```
data = r + "," + g + "," + b + "," + "255"
ser = serial.Serial(port='/dev/ttyACM0', baudrate=9600, parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE, bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS, timeout=1)


time.sleep(2)
ser.write(data.encode())
ser.close()
```